# Handling events from puppeteer's page context outside evaluate method

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My goal is to open puppeteer-chromium instance as a child process in nodejs environment and listen to all clicks that user will make in a way that these events are accessible from parent process. So I think stream of events is needed but I have no idea how to send them from evaluate method (process object is not accessible in that context - 'process is undefined' in logs of chromium).

Currently I'm trying to add click listener inside page's context but is there any way to obtain those events outside of evaluate method?

I know evaluate method can return promise but it's only one value so it's not enough. I'd like to gather all clicks until I close chromium window.

Thanks in advance for all kind of advices.

My sample code:

```
  // parent.js
  const child = require('child_process');
  const childprocess = child.fork('./childprocess.js');
  childprocess.on('message', (msg) => {
      console.log('Message from child', msg);
      // here I'd like to get click events from childprocess
      // eg. saving them in database
  });

  // childprocess.js
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  (async () => {
      await process.on('message', (m) => {
        process.send(m)
      })
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('http://someurl.com');
      await page.evaluate( (processHandle) => {
        document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          console.log(event);  // event is logged in chromium dev console
          processHandle.send({msg: event}); // nothing happens
        })
      }, process);
  })()
```

Comment: *I'd like to gather all clicks* - how many are there, where are they and how is the script supposed to know that that there will be no more? That's the problem here. A promise is supposed to be finished with time. A stream of DOM events isn't. You probably have XY problem. Consider explaining your case in details instead of investigating potentially wrong solution.

Comment: `You probably have XY problem. Consider explaining your case in details instead of investigating potentially wrong solution` — Can't agree more. Please add details of what you want to accomplish

Comment: @estus I've tried to explain it more, tell me if this is clear to understand.

Comment: So clicks are supposed to be done by a user. What do you intend to use them for in parent process? Please, post the entire (pseudo)code that is related to clicks, this may help to understand your case.

Comment: @estus Now you should have some bigger picture I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the sample code is that `processHandle` won’t be serialized in such a way that JavaScript in the context of the document can use it. You can instead [expose a function on `window`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.5.0/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) that will do what you want:

```
await page.exposeFunction("sendEventToProcessHandle", (event) => {
    processHandle.send({ msg: JSON.parse(event) });
})

await page.evaluate((processHandle) => {
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        window.sendEventToProcessHandle(JSON.stringify(e));
    });
}, process)
```

Here, `window.sendEventToProcessHandle` is a function that will run in the context of the Node.JS process, where you can access `processHandle`, but can be called by the document.

Comment: Not exactly worked but I've managed to pass process object by using it in 'exposeFunction'. There is one problem left. In chromium I logged out whole event eg. MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 152, screenY: 266, clientX: 130, clientY: 107, …} but after sending to parent there is only {isTrusted:true}

Comment: Odd. If it were mangling native objects I could understand that but numbers are serializable. If you log `event` inside `sendEventToProcessHandle`, is it still missing those fields?

Comment: No @Aankhen, after sending event to puppeteer's context it gets smaller. All fields of event are accessible only from evaluate context.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer to include JSON-ification. Could you see if that works?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and does not work, it's related with serialization problem regarding events. I will just choose needed properties and send them as separate object.

Comment: I see. That solution makes sense.